# Running a loop with starting condition in one column and ending condition in second column

Tags: r

i have a file that has 29 columns.I am interested in 2 columns (Speed and load). My question is: what code should i write so that R can **start** to copy all the rows and columns when **speed ==0 & load == any number apart from zero**. The copying should **stop when speed is not equal to zero and load can be any number not equal to zero**.

```
Sl.No    Speed    Load
1         29      0
2         30      0
3         0       60
4         0       120
5         0       180
6         10      180
```

When R finds speed ==0 and load is not equal to zero, It should copy all the data from sl.no 3 till speed is not equal to zero (sl.no 6). I need to make this process in a loop. All the data that R gets from the looping process should be put into a new Data frame.

Comment: Does this answer your question: `new_df <- df[df$Speed == 0L & df$Load != 0L, ]` ?

Comment: @Apom: you sir are a genius. thank you. Just one more question. What is the significance of L that you put after 0?

Comment: check out the results of `typeof(1)` versus `typeof(1L)`.

Comment: @lmo  Thanks lmo. So i faced another problem which i ran Apom's code. Everything seems to run properly but there are a lot of values that have zero speed and load has some random value. I would like R to look at the rows one by one and stop as soon as speed is detected. Then run the loop again from start. Is that possible?

Comment: @Apom:  i faced another problem which i ran the code. Everything seems to run properly but there are a lot of values that have zero speed and load has some random value. I would like R to look at the rows one by one and stop as soon as speed is detected. Then run the loop again from start. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe you want something like `which.min(df$Speed > 0L)` to get the first row where speed is greater than 0 or `which.min(df$Speed == 0L & df$Load != 0L)` for both conditions.

Comment: @lmo doesnt seem to work :-/